# Should 'openssl verify' recognise an exceeded 'Max Path Length' on a root CA?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

#### Background

Following the guides [here](https://fernandobarillas.com/blog/2015/07/22/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-root-certificate-with-cf-ssl/) and [here](https://fernandobarillas.com/blog/2015/08/06/creating-an-intermediate-ca-for-mitmproxy/) I am setting up a multi-level PKI. I have increased the pathlen config to 3, such that I can generate one root certificate that I can use to sign the first intermediate and store securely. The first intermediate will be stored on the configuration workstation and be used to generate second intermediates, which will be used to generate the final certificates actually used for communication within a remote cluster.

#### /Background

In experimenting around with this I found that if I reduce the pathlen value used to generate the CA, even to 0, then in a command such as this:

```
openssl verify -CAfile <root ca> -untrusted <chain of intermediates> \
    <cert to verify>
```

the certificate is still validated as OK. I would have expected the Max Path Length of the CA to make this certificate invalid, is this wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: See OpenSSL's [`verify` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/verify.html) and the discussion of `-verify_depth`.

Comment: I did consider SuperUser for posting this question, but it didn't seem to fit when I reminded myself of the criteria on the tour page (for both sites) Unix and Linux actually seems like the better option, thanks for the suggestion. I did look into -verify_depth, but it didn't seem to be related to the constraints that pathlen specifies, but more for a user to set a hard limit on the number of intermediate trusts that is acceptable for the particular verification.

Comment: For the PKI design questions, [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) is probably your best bet. For information on using commands like `openssl`, [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is usually a good choice. If you show some code with your question so that it appears to be related to programming, then I leave the question alone. I cast the close vote when its clearly not programming related.

Comment: I think information security is indeed the place for this as the problem probably comes from a misunderstanding (mine) of how the constraint is supposed to work, and there's nothing about the code I'm using that would change that. I'll open a question on this over there and close this happily when I have the opportunity tomorrow morning.

Comment: Honestly, you will probably get better answers about PKI design and implementation at InfoSec.SE. I've set up a couple of in-house PKIs, and when I have questions, that's where I go. Or, you can try the [PKIX mailing list](https://www.ietf.org/mailman/listinfo/pkix). PKIX is the Internet's PKI as detailed by the IETF. (The thing is, PKIs are like automobiles. They are all mostly the same, but they have differences. Its like all cars mostly drive the same, but GM, Ford, Chevy, Mercedes, BMW, Volvo, etc are all different when it come to service and parts).